# Get exist words from text with regex

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I am using firebase ml kit for words recognition in images. Actually it works pretty good. But sometimes it`s returns some kind of gibrish. So my question is any library exist for recognition exist words from text? (String) Or maybe I can use some kind of regex combination to get such result. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: yes you can achieve this by using https://developers.google.com/vision/android/text-overview  
or OPENCV in your app

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using regex. store all values in List or Arraylist and then match each value or position of list with proper regex. it will take time but at least you can't get 100% result but 75-80% it will work.